# Why isn't bitronix (BTM) binding the user transaction into JNDI?

Tags: java, jta, bitronix

Looks like Bitronix, as suggested elsewhere, works very well.  However, I'm stumped by a problem with it.  I get this exception from Hibernate, when I attempt to save the session *after* I call `TransactionManager.begin()`:

```
14:21:32,350 ERROR [JTATransaction] Could not find UserTransaction in JNDI
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name UserTransaction is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:769)
```

I can't see any evidence that Bitronix binds the user transaction to JNDI.  How do I make it do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered here: https://github.com/bitronix/btm/blob/master/btm-docs/src/main/asciidoc/Hibernate2x.adoc#txManager

In a nutshell, there is no way for BTM to automatically bind itself to Tomcat's JNDI server unless you change the Tomcat config yourself. This is explained here: https://github.com/bitronix/btm/blob/master/btm-docs/src/main/asciidoc/TomcatWithBtm2x.adoc

Comment: plz fix your links or replace them with the real documentation as both links are now dead and thus your answer is useless.

Comment: Done. But that's speaking about an outdated version of Hibernate, I'm not sure it's still useful now.